# MariaDB variable 'have_ssl' still DISABLED after setting certificate path in my.ini (Windows)

Tags: windows, windows-10, mariadb

Following the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/securing-connections-for-client-and-server/), variables must be set:

```
[mariadb]
...
ssl_cert = /etc/my.cnf.d/certificates/server-cert.pem
ssl_key = /etc/my.cnf.d/certificates/server-key.pem
ssl_ca = /etc/my.cnf.d/certificates/ca.pem
```

Translating to windows, as seen in other answers taking precautions for `\s` and `/s` escape.

```
[mariadb]
ssl_cert="C://Users//myUser//MariaDB//SSL_Certs//server-cert.pem"
ssl_key="C://Users//myUser//MariaDB//SSL_Certs//server-key.pem"
ssl_ca="C://Users//myUser//MariaDB//SSL_Certs//ca.pem"
ssl=true
```

However, after connecting:

- `show variables like 'have_ssl';` is `DISABLED` instead of `YES`.
- `show session status like 'ssl_cipher';` is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Open `services.msc` and find the MariaDB service, and take note of the "Log On As" username. Give `Read` and `List folder contents` permissions to the `"C://Users//myUser//MariaDB//SSL_Certs//` directory, to the **user name in the "Log On As" column** (in my case NETWORK SERVICE).

After this, `show variables like 'have_ssl';` was set to `YES`.